# Error running C++ program eclipse (nothing to build)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am getting strange error. I configured my eclipse for c/c++. when I build my c/c++ project they are getting build successfully. When I run my c binary it shows  **nothing to build**  and then actually runs the program and shows the output.

Now, the fun part is when I execute c++ binary it also shows nothing to build and shows nothing.

Comment: Are you running your binary from within eclipse? I.e. `CTRL+F11` or clicking the green "run" button? "Nothing to build" is probably a message from eclipse that no source files have changed so it won't rebuild your executable before running it. Try executing from the command line. What do you see?

Comment: Try compiling your program with `make` so write your `Makefile`

Answer (score 0):

Ok had the same problem.
Try

- to see in the console if any other previous processes are still running, If they do the red square (for stopping it forced) is there at least
- to clean your project (right click project then clean), if that doesn't do the deal
- use right click project, then compil. Then again right click the project, then use `run as`, and select the option that apears there.

Hope it helps, good luck

Comment: Hi , I am doing that way only . First , I build the project. Then , I run the binary as c/c++ application. Anyhow , every time I run it , it builds also. So , I tried executing the binary files from the workspace by double clicking. The c binary is executiing properly but c++ binary is giving this error : <i> the program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing from your computer </i>

Comment: This should do the job, fallow the tutorial http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2010/03/03/shared-libraries-with-eclipse-cdt-and-cygwin-on-windows/

Comment: or tell what you at project properties/C/C++ build / Toolchaine editor and project properties/C/C++ general path and simbols / click on GNU C have for instance i have the ming includes there.