# Eclipse stuck building project

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to build a project in eclipse and it keeps getting stuck around 10%. I have previously been able to build projects without a problem and I have not changed anything since last building a project which was last night.

The console says:
 20:42:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\test.o" "..\src\test.cpp"

I have tried running other projects but get the same result. I have also closed eclipse and relaunched multiple times. The progress bar does not move with time either.

I followed instructions here [Error running C++ program eclipse (nothing to build)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038283/error-running-c-program-eclipse-nothing-to-build) but it did nothing. All projects were able to clean successfully but still can not build.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check on the process to see if it's still running? You might at least be able to tell if it's stuck in an infinite loop or waiting for some event.

Comment: Yeah I killed eclipse, g++, starter, and misc processes. Even after restarting the computer it still has the same issues.

Comment: That's not what I meant. When you see there is no progress did you check on the process to see if it was still running? That would give a better idea what kind of bug you're facing

Comment: Sorry, yes the process is still running.

Comment: Running idle or using cpu?

Comment: It was running idle. I did a clean install of eclipse and my compiler and now it is working. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Idle process means it's usually waiting on some interrupt, maybe because it couldn't access a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by doing a clean install of eclipse and the compiler.